# Ground state of the Heisenberg XXX model with a coupling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spin-models, ferromagnetism, spin-chains

I have a one-dimensional Heisenberg chain with a Magnetic field with $N$ sites with $J>0$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H} = -J \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} \vec{S_i}\cdot \vec{S_{i+1}}- \sum_{i = 1}^N \vec{H}\cdot S_i
\end{equation}
where the spins $\vec{S_i} = (S_i^x, S_i^y, S_i^z)$ live in 3 dimensions. What is the ground state of such a system. I know that without the external magnetic field one of the ground states is just all the spins pointing upwards such that $S_i^z = S$ for all $i$. But how does the ground state change in the presence of an external field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spins will all point along the field, i.e., $\displaystyle\langle \vec S_i\rangle = S\frac{\vec H}{|\vec H|}$.

(That this is indeed the ground state is easily verified: The corresponding state -- a product state of all spins pointing in that direction -- already minimizes the energy of each of the terms in the Hamiltonian individually.)

Comment: Thank you, I see it now.